# Angular Subject: share only with some of the observers

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subject-observer

Given a basic type

```ts
export interface Item {
  id: string;
}
```

I define a class `BackupClient` with a `Subject`:

```ts
export class BackupClient {
  private subject = new Subject<Item>();

  private share(item: Item): void {
    this.subject.next(item);
  }

  public subscribe(observer?: Partial<Observer<Item>>): Subscription {
    return this.subject.subscribe(observer);
  }
}
```

Via the `BackupService` a component `ItemComponent` may subscribe to my `BackupClient` and update its `item` whenever `BackupClient` shares a new `item`.

```ts
import { BackupClient } from './backup.client';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BackupService {
  constructor() {}

  public client = new BackupClient();
}
```

```ts
import { BackupService } from '../backup.service';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from '../item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css'],
})
export class ItemComponent {
  constructor(private backupService: BackupService) {
    this.backupService.client.subscribe({
      next: (item) => {
        if (this.id === item.id) {
          this.item = item;
        }
      },
    });
  }

  @Input() id?: string | null;

  protected item?: Item | null;
}
```

In may app I now have many `ItemComponent` instances. By checking the `id` inside my observer I avoid an update of all components if only one `item` changes.

I would like to improve this by using some kind of `Subject` or multicasting design that only shares with observers of some `id`. That is, still all components subscribe to one `Subject`, but sharing is constrained to only those `ItemComponent`s with given `id`.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-naufsc?file=src/item.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want subscribers to only receive emissions if the emission is for an item with a specific `id`.

In that case, you could modify your `subscribe()` method to take in the id and filter out emissions from other items:

```js
  public subscribe(id: string, observer?: Partial<Observer<Item>>): Subscription {
    return this.subject.pipe(
        filter(item => item.id === id)
    ).subscribe(observer);
  }
```

```js
this.backupService.client.subscribe(this.id, ...);
```

The above code won't work in the constructor, because the `@Input() id` will be undefined until at least the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook.

---

The `subscribe` method of your `BackupClient` class is probably introducing memory leaks.  Each time a consumer calls `.subscribe()`, you create a subscription, but it doesn't appear that you have a way to ever unsubscribe from them.  You may want to consider returning an Observable that consumers subscribe to, then the consumer can be responsible of unsubscribing:

```js
public item(id: string) {
  return this.subject.pipe(
    filter(item => item.id === id)
  );
}
```

Then in your component:

```js
this.backupService.client.item(this.id).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks alot, exactly what I was looking, also thx for the additional notes.